# C# Change selected object from a list without changing the original list

Tags: c#, linq

Here I've selected the record which a want to get into a new variable. and after that, when I'm changing the value of 'itm.note' it's automatically modifying the original list (Obj.Testlist) as well. How can this be avoided? Only want to change 'itm' object and Obj.Testlist list should be keep as it is.

var itm = Obj.Testlist.Where(x => x.id == 1).SingleOrDefault();

itm.note = "text";

Comment: Do you have a way of cloning the object? Have you considered using Records? What is the datatype of the elements in your list?

Comment: @gunr2171 I didn't try to clone the object. trying to find if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: @gunr2171  The list is a object list of a view model, and the type of note is string.

Comment: Classes use by Ref so you need to copy the object to have two different copies of object.

Comment: @jdweng Can you suggest a better way to make a copy of a large object?

Comment: See following : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/09/09/cloning-objects-in-c-and-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

You could clone the fetched item, but that wouldn't be efficient.

How about this:

```
var changedFetchedItem = Obj.Testlist.Where(x => x.id == 1)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Id = 1,
        Note = "text",

        // copy the other properties that you plan to use
        // don't copy the ones that you don't use.
    }
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Since you will be fetching at utmost one item, this is very efficient.

I chose to create an object with anonymous type. If you need a specific type, you can add the type after the keyword `new`

Comment: Thanks, this is great. but in the model there are more than 150 properties. So that I've used cloning.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have large model, decided to use cloning for this (Sample code),

```
public class TestClone : ICloneable
    {
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public string ErrorDetail { get; set; }

        public object Clone()
        {
            return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test1 = new TestClone() { IsSuccess = true, Note= "text", ErrorDetail = "DTL1" };
        var test2 = (TestClone) test1.Clone();
        test2.Note= "new text";
    }
```